# T-SQL Join Query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have been trying to write a query for a view but I can't seem to get it... I have two tables that I need to join... but what I need is that for every ID in table 1 I get all records on table 2. For Example:

> ```
>  Table 1       Table 2
>   Jhon          Car
>   Bill          House
>                 Jet
> ```

I would like to get:

> ```
>   Table 3
>   Jhon   Car
>   Jhon   House
>   Jhon   Jet
>   Bill   Car
>   Bill   House
>   Bill   Jet
> ```

P.S. Data on both tables can vary.
P.S.S. Table 1 is actually a Left Outer Join between two other tables where the first table contains the indexes and the second contains the field used to create relation to Table 2.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need a `CROSS JOIN` for this (AKA Cartesian Product).

```
SELECT t1.col, t2.col
FROM Table1 t1 cross join Table2 t2
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
select * from table1, table2
```

or use a CROSS JOIN if database supports it

Comment: SQL Server does support it so I think it's best practice to use the explicit syntax so it is clear that it is intentional!

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( { } ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: This is the "old-style" JOIN syntax - which is both deprecated (you should use explicit joins, e.g. INNER JOIN; OUTER JOIN, CROSS JOIN, as needed) and also less clear and less obvious in my opinion. I would **avoid** this syntax if ever possible

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    table1
CROSS JOIN
        table2
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select columns you want to get
from Table1 Cross Join Table2
```