# Join rows with same UnitOfMeasureId from two different tables

Tags: sql, azure-data-studio

I know this is pretty basic, but I am having trouble figuring out this syntax and there is not a lot of content that I could find for these type of sql queries.

I have a UnitOfMeasure Table in my db, then I have UnitOfMeasureSize. UOM Size has sizes for the UnitOfMeasure and each row has the their specific UnitOfMeasure Id.

I want to write a sql query to grab the Unit of Measure, then each UOM size by the UOM Id.

[image: Unit Of Measure]
[image: Unit Of Measure Size]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [T-SQL Join Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4680275/t-sql-join-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that the upper table is 'table1' and the below table as 'table2'

```
SQL> SELECT table1.UnitOfMeasureId, table2.UnitOfMeasureSize FROM Table1 INNER JOIN table2 WHERE table1.UnitOfMeasureId = table2.UnitOfMeasureId;
```